# Error while pass multiple values through command argument in Grid View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Page Directory is showing errorl like **"New line is constatant"** when I try to pass  multiple values through command argument  in Grid View. If I pass one value through command arguments, there is no error. Why it shows error like this?? My page directory and gridview is mention below

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Home.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LeaveApprove.aspx.cs" Inherits="Samples.WebForm133" %>
  </asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"  
       runat="server">
 </asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">                 
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <td align="center">
 <asp:GridView ID="gvemployee" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" 
  CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" onrowcommand="gvemployee_RowCommand"                                                                     
 <Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"                                           
  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("EmpCode")+","+ Eval("Fromdate",,"+  
  Eval("Todate")%>'>Approve</asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server"                                        
  CommandArgument='<%#Eval("EmpCode")+","+ Eval("Fromdate",,"+    
  Eval("Todate")%>'>Reject</asp:LinkButton>
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
   </td>
   </tr>
  </asp:Content>
```

Is there any other method to pass multiple arguments in gridview ?

Comment: you can do this two ways:-1.create a property combining these columns value & then write that property in the command argument.2. use Stirng,Format("{0},{1}",<%#Eval("EmpCode")%>,<%#Eval("Todate")%>).

Comment: Use Gridview Datakeys property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write the above line as seen below:

```
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("EmpCode")+","+ Eval("Fromdate") + "," + Eval("Todate")%>'
```